# Compile WASM which depends on QTCore libraries

Tags: c++, qtcore, webassembly, emcc

I have a MS Visual Studio 2015 project, where I created a class Test:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QTCore/qstring.h>    

class Test
    {
    public:
        Test(){QString str = "Hello";
        std::cout << str.size();};
        ~Test();
    };
```

In the visual studio project properties, I have linked the QTCore libraries and included. The build in VS is successfull.

Now, I want use this class to create web-assembly api.
To compile this code in web-assembly I ran following command in terminal:

```
em++ "Test.cpp" -s WASM=1 -o test.html
```

I got following error:

```
Test.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'QTCore/qstring.h' file not found
#include <QTCore/qstring.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

How to build the classes which depend on some other external libraries?

Comment: Did the answer below help you or do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this C example, which should be portable and almost identical to the C++ library building.  Once you have your QTCore source folder on your system, it should build without issues.  See below:

[How Link External C Library to WebAssembly Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823819/how-link-external-c-library-to-webassembly-build/61839789#61839789)